# Unable to debug with embedded gdb server in Clion

Tags: cmake, embedded, clion, gdbserver, segger-jlink

I have a problem with making the gdb-debug to work in CLION
I am using J-Link GDB server and arm-none-eabi-gdb as debugger in Windows10
The compilation is complete and following files are created under the cmake-build-debug folder (Note: I have used -g -Og for compiling with -DDEBUG flag).

[Generated files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVv4m.png)

The problem that I have is with debugging using the arm-none-eabi-gdb debugger in the **Embedded GDB Server configuration in the CLion** configuration, simply it does not work properly when I execute the debug from CLion.

To be more detailed I am using following configuration (I am also using J-Link hardware as my debugger connected via SWD on a STM32F103RBT6 board).

My CMakeLists.txt file  (last part is UPLOAD Target) is depicted below

[CmakeLists.txt UPLOAD section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezEKl.png)
Note: the *arm-none-eabi-gdb and JLinkGDBServerCL* both are in the Windows PATH environment

While using the command line I can easily debug with no issues (note I go to the build folder and run the arm-none-eabi-gdb from there) and in the image below one can see everything works fine
[look at the (gdb) commands] while the Jlink GDB server GUI is running in the background with configuration like the image below

[JLinkGDBServer GUI that I run before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZhBs.png)

And the gdb communication works fine as below

[gdb from cmd prompt inside the build folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o26N5.png)

And the same result I get when I use following CLI GDB Server in another command prompt window as by executing following command 
**"C:\Program Files (x86)\SEGGER\JLink\JLinkGDBServerCL.exe" -port 2331 -s -device STM32F103RB -endian little -speed 1000 -vd -select USB -if swd -noir -singlerun -strict**

but from Clion side I get two problems with the CLion's **Embedded GDB Server** Debug configuration

Firstly in the image below it never executes the GDB server at all
[CLion Embedded GDB server configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KQNk.png)

I get following error result image please note that I generate CMakeLists.txt file before every try and then rebuild the project every time before debugging.

[Embedded GDB Server configuration output and execution result-Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWPxn.png)

I would like to know if there is something wrong with my setting or whether there is bug with CLion Embedded GDB Server or not!?
Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Stackoverflow rules require that error messages must be posted as text not as pictures, and in the body of the question.  It would appear your gdbserver us not running or using a different port than you try to connect to it on.

Comment: You put a lot of effort into the question, but the goal of SO is that it should be useful to future readers as well. This is why you need to include all the texts into the question - imgur pictures die quickly, and it's hard to read.